Can the translation of a book be an obstacle?
I have a book and I wrote it not in English. However, I have made a translation into English, a pretty good one. Will native English speakers read such a book or will they, when they see the translation, immediately realize that it is a translation and they will not feel comfortable reading the book? The translation was done by a non-native speaker – if it's an important detail.

I agree that you need to get the book translated or at least reviewed by a native speaker. As an example, here's a link where you can read an extract from a self-published book by a friend of a friend of mine. Personally I think she's a great writer and I would love to read a "language-corrected" version of her book, but the minor linguistic errors are really jarring: https://www.amazon.com/My-Little-Ship-Forever-Sea/dp/1528940962

Voicing support for translations, one of my favorite authors is Swedish (Fredrik Backman) though his success would provide a lot of extra support in the process

Few will be uncomfortable with the idea that the book is a translation... many books are. But few people will be willing to waste their time and energy with a bad translation... if it's hard work to read it, nobody will.

The question has several small but noticeable giveaways that you’re not a native English-speaker — most clearly “I wrote it not in English”.   Not at all the sort of things that cause any problems in everyday communication, but absolutely at the level that will detract from reading a novel and hurt whatever stylistic effects you’re aiming to achieve, if you did the translation yourself.

I agree with the technical advice given in all answers. You do need a native speaker to review the translation. However, I'm quite saddened by how every answerer seems to reject anything that doesn't come from their own culture. "not to mention cultural allusions I don't get", "the actual or perceived cultural origin of the text might present an obstacle", "those styles and themes and characters didn't appeal to me" The world is full of wonderful cultures. Don't censor yourself by fear that a handful of English speakers won't like non-English culture.

I wouldn't be prejudiced against it just because it is a translation.
The problem would be a not-great translation. If as a native English speaker I am stumbling over word order, or missing bits of grammar or incorrectly used words or awkward phrases, I will put the book down.
For me, a book has to read seamlessly or I cannot sustain the immersion of being in the scene. Every time I am reading and stumble over a sentence, I drop out of immersion and imagination and into analytic proofreader mode. Just a typo does that to me, not to mention twisted grammar or cultural allusions I don't get.
As a non-native speaker, you might think the English translation is good, but I might think it is awful.
You need a native English speaking editor (which you might find at a reasonable price on Fiverr) to read your opening scene, and perhaps a dozen other pages from throughout the book, including action, emotional, scene description, definitely dialogue and conversation and flag for you any awkward writing that gives away you are not a native English speaker.
Then you'll know the quality of the translation.
To be clear, it is not a prejudice against any foreign culture, it is just a matter of whether the writing breaks my immersion or not. If it does, it is too much work for me to read; I read stories to escape into that immersion.

Puns or wordplay are an especially important aspect here: words that may sounds similar to a non-native speaker in their accent, will not necessarily sound the same to native speakers.  A good native speaker can find a nearest-equivalent to preserve the intent, even if this means the translation is not necessarily literal/direct. Indeed, in translating HP: Chamber of Secrets to German, Mr Weasley mistakenly says “Trolltreppen” (“Troll-Stairs”) instead of “Rolltreppen” (“Escalator”, lit. “Rolling Stairs”) — a much better joke than him merely saying “Escapator” in the original English.

Or, at the other end of the spectrum: the name of the manga series “To Love Ru” is a pun based on the words "Love" — which sounds like "Rabu" when said with a strong Japanese accent — and "Trouble" — which sounds like "Toraburu" with the same accent. The author refused suggestions for the name change in translation, insisting that native speakers would understand the pun… but “what does the name mean?” became one of the most frequently asked questions at conventions or Q&A sessions!

As an example of that, the Chinese-written novel Three Body Problem has a fair number of footnotes in the English translation... some of which are explicitly calling out wordplay that the translator couldn't reproduce in English.

A related note - other books in that series were translated by different people, and it's very obvious that the first and third books in were translated by the same person and that the second was not. It's like they were written by different authors, which isn't too far from the truth... the translator may not be creating the story, but they're effectively doing all the same word-smithing that the original author did. Never underestimate the contribution of a good translator.

To achieve a good translation, it is almost always necessary to have a native speaker of the target language edit the translation. It is better to have the translation done by a native speaker, but that costs money. I have had a very painful time with non-fiction written in German and translated into English by the authors.
The sentence structures were often difficult to follow, the terminology and figures of speech were strange, and the whole experience was unpleasant. I persisted because I wanted to know about the subject, but I would not have read it for enjoyment.

Agreed.  I have encountered many non-native English speakers online who speak (write) excellent English, and I have no trouble understanding them, but there are subtle turns of phrase or word orderings that just don't feel natural to me.  They aren't incorrect, but they're just not smooth.

I don't believe the translation as such, if the translation is good, will present an obstacle. But the actual or percieved cultural origin of the text might. I'll give you an example for what I mean.
I've been reading mostly science fiction and fantasy for a long time now. I first encountered the genres in my teens through translations (into German) of American and British authors. As my proficiency in English grew, I eventually switched to reading the texts in their English original. Sometimes I encountered science fiction or fantasy in German or (as translations) by a French, Spanish, or Russian writers.
Until about a decade or so ago, I unvariably disliked all the non-American and non-British science fiction and fantasy. Science fiction and fantasy novels from each of those European cultures were quite distinct from English novels (and from each other). Their stories, characters, and narrative style was specific to their cultural background and that culture's literary tradition. And those styles and themes and characters didn't appeal to me.
I did switch from reading English novels in German translations to reading them in the original English, because often (but not always) the German translations weren't very good. But as long as I wasn't able to read them in English, the fact that they were translated didn't keep me from reading them. Now that I can read in English, I do avoid translations, not only from English but from other languages (that I don't speak) as well. But originally that wasn't an obstacle for me. What was an obstacle were the different cultural backgrounds. I actually found that novels from Australia and South Africa, few as they were, differed thematically from the British and American ones and I tended to avoid them, even though they weren't translations.
This has changed a lot by now. Russian, German, and French science fiction and fantasy has been "Americanized" thoroughly and they read (or, in the case of movies, view) just like novels (or movies) from American and British authors. I have been reading some German SF&F recently and enjoyed it a lot. I have yet to explore the current French and Russian (and Australian) works again, but it doesn't keep me from doing so that some of it will be translated.
But again, the requirement for a translation not to be an obstacle is that it has to be good. To native speakers the text must read as if it was written by a native speaker. For that, you need a native speaker who can write well and has been trained as a translator. Translating is a craft that requires learning it. At the very least you should get feedback on the language of a longer text sample (e.g. a chapter) from a larger group of native speakers to make sure your non-native translation is good enough. Or it will indeed be an obstacle.

s/unvariably/invariably/.  (I wouldn't normally mention such a tiny error in otherwise-excellent English -- but it does rather illustrate your point :-)

@gidds Oops, thank you. But if that mistake serves my argument I'll leave it uncorrected :-)

This answer is focused on your personal perspective; other people may have different ones (for example, I'm the counter example as the Witcher tales totally blew me away because they followed non-American culture and storytelling patterns). The OP was concerned more about the impact across all members of his audience, not about your (or my) personal preference, I think.

@toolforger My experience is that I'm never the only one with a certain taste but a representative of a certain market segment. Therefore I presented my personal views as "an example". This is, I believe, the best we can do for OP here, because I'm unaware of any systematic study of the topic. The alternative would have been to give no answer, which would have been even less helpful.

@toolforger In writing, there are some things (like prologues or viewpoint switches) that do not appeal to all readers, while there are other things (like no prologue and no viewpoint switches) that appeal to all readers. I believe, translations fall into the same category. Some readers will avoid translations, while no reader will avoid a book because it isn't a translation. Being aware of what may reduce your potential readership (and can be easily avoided by not having a prologue, not having viewpoint switches, and writing in English) helps you not limit your audience unnecessarily.

TL;DR: Unambitious  books don't lose much from equally unambitious translations. However, there are not many great books, works of art, in which language is unimportant. They need a correspondingly competent translation to minimize what gets lost in it.

It depends a lot on what kind of book you are talking about. The majority of books, even much more so the majority of copies sold, are meant to be read once and thrown away. They are "cheap" (literally, because they only exist as mass market editions, and figuratively) entertainment. Romance novels, many franchise science fiction series, many detective stories. The main purpose of language in such books is to drive the action forward. It has not much of an intrinsic value. Not much, if anything, would therefore be lost in a quick and dirty translation: The action is what's important here.
On the other end of the spectrum are great works of literary art. In many of them, language plays a central role. Kafka, Joyce, even Kerouac. Some books modify language and make that an integral part of the story, like Tolkien's Lord of the Rings or Burgess's A Clockwork Orange. Not only is language an integral part of such books — they also tend to attract a readership to whom language is important and who appreciates masterful language.
In order to preserve the work, this latter category needs careful translation, ideally by another master of language — just not (only) the original one. Such  translators who are themselves poets are rare and semi-celebrities in their circles.
Whether a translation by a non-native speaker will hurt your book depends very much on the book.

I’ve never seen a book that improved upon translation. The quality will inevitably diminish when reworking an original. In fact, seeing on the cover page that a book has been translated is a reliable red flag to temper my expectations for such book. Having said that, some books are so good that they’re still very much worth reading even as a replica.
